# After changing typescript breakpoints fail to set correctly and main-client.js keeps loading itself into Visual Studio 2017

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I'm not sure what's going on here, I'm using Visual Studio 2017 running a React-Redux project with typescript (the default visual studio template).

Breakpoints do not initially bind when the webpage loads, I have to re-set them in visual studio.

If I change the typescript and try to place a breakpoint visual studio loads 'main-client.js' (which is a huge js file) and puts the breakpoint at the bottom of the typescript file.

The kicker is if I go into main-client.js and find the compiled javascript code equivalent of where I'm setting the breakpoint and put it there it actually switches me back to the typescript file and places the breakpoint correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that we do need set the breakpoint in VS. After setting your breakpoint and run your project using IE (or Chrome),  your breakpoint will be hit in your ts file and you can step through the code in the VS environment (**not in the browser code debug window**).

The code will transition to js if it jumps to another file for which there is no matching ts file, and then transition back again to ts again when it can.
Reference link:

[How do I debug typescript code in VS 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944682/how-do-i-debug-typescript-code-in-vs-2017][1])

Hope this helps.