# Visual studio 2017 debugger not working after Office Excel Add-in Typescript conversion

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, office-js, office-addins

I am new to Office Add-ins and I am learning to develop Excel add-ins with visual studio 2017 (community) version 15.9.3. I followed the Microsoft guide how to convert an add-in as instructed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript

But when you do that, the debugger will never hit the breakpoints anymore:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No Symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

I know this threat has already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927103/typescript-debugging-not-working-in-visual-studio-2017) and I followed all of the steps including:

- Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)
- Enable browser link
- Clear cache
- Change output browser

There is also another thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944682/how-do-i-debug-typescript-code-in-vs-2017/40944703#40944703), which I also followed

I have no idea where to search anymore. If I create a new visual studio project->office add-in-> insert content into Excel Spreadsheets in plain JavaScript the debugger works immediately.

***Update 7 December Some progress***

Today I tried something else. I went to the site from Microsoft for converting an existing project to typescript and I found out that there is a bug on their site:
[Convert to typescript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript)

They state that your tsconfig.JSON should contain the following code:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es5", "dom", "es2015.promise" ]
}
```

}

But when you try to add a new item to your project and choose the predefined .JSON Typescript config file and you add the above settings you get this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es5", "dom", "es2015.promise" ]

  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

The debugger will be started then BUT it will go to the converted Home.JS file and not the Home.TS. The problem with this is that you have to debug generated JavaScript and it throws an exception

> Unhandled exception at line 2, column 5 in https://localhost:44327/Home/Home.js
>   0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Promise' is undefined

so my TypeScript does nothing!

Does anyone know how you can force Visual studio to debug the TypeScript file and not the generated JS file?

kind regards,

Comment: Do either of these articles help? [Attach Debugger from Task Pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane), [Debug Add-ins Using F12 Developer Tools on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10)

Comment: Hi Rick. I tried all of them but to no avail. Is there no real debugging in Visual Studio 2017???? So using TypeScript for Office JS development is not really an option?

Comment: I think Microsoft does not know what they are doing with the web add-ins. I also commented on the website of microsoft:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/convert-javascript-to-typescript. There is no response and like always, trying to call somebody at Microsoft is climbing the Mount Everest without legs. So I think I will drop the TypeScript story

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy also, but finally figured it out, like mentioned in the updates the project Typescript settings are disabled because there is a tsconfig.json file defined, this provides all the TypeScript settings so all you have to do is update your tsconfig.json file to output sourcemaps.

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "lib": [ "es5", "dom", "es2015.promise" ]
  }
}
```

Not sure if this is related but I did go into the Debug settings and enable Enable `JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET`

Here is a copy of my Debug Settings just incase:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the feedback but I already enabled this option and also when you click on the start button, you have to enable script debugging, which also is enabled. I would really like that Michael Zlatkovsky adds a chapter in his book how to cope with this because he does not say any word how to convert to Typescript and which are the burdens to tackle.
Regards,